# RecyclerView data move to other items when I scroll or add new item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a recyclerView that I can add items and each item has EditText and CheckBox, ImageView, etc.

I successfully created the feature of adding new Item and it holds the data with `TextWatcher` in `onBindViewHolder()`. And the data of TextView stays well.

This is `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final EditMessageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        MessageItem item = items.get(position);
        holder.messageET.setText(item.getMessage());
        holder.messageET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                items.get(position).setMessage(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }
```

This is `addItem()` and `getMessageItem()` in the Adapter:

```
    public void addItem(MessageItem messageItem) {
        items.add(messageItem);
        notifyItemInserted(items.size());
    }

    public ArrayList<MessageItem> getMessageItems() {
        return items;
    }
```

However, the problem is when I add more items or scroll up or down. The data mix in wrong orders and wrong data. How can I handle this problem and How can I prevent this problem with CheckBox and ImageView as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of using position in your onBindViewHolder(), try using adapter position. Which might solve your problem.

```
MessageItem item = items.get(position);
```

Instead use

```
MessageItem item = items.get(holder.adapterPosition);
```

Let me know if this works.

If this doesn't work try using notifyItemInsertedRange instead notifyiteminserted.

Thanks

Comment: Where can I get `adapterPosition`? The parameters are just `holder` and `position`.

Comment: holder.adapterPosition @c-an . and try this and do let me know  whether it works or not?

Comment: I guess It's working! Thanks. What's the difference?? What was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setHasFixedSized(true) or setHasStableIds(true) method?

First method will allow RecyclerView to avoid invalidating the whole layout when its adapter contents change.
Second method set stable ids to each items.

Comment: No, I never tried `setHasFixedSized(true)` or `setHasStableIds(true)`. Where should I put the methods? In Activity? or Which part in Adapter?

Comment: You can use in activity/fragment like `yourRecylerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` after setting up your adapter to recyclerview

Comment: what about `setHasStableIds(true)`?

Comment: `setHasFixedSized(true)` fixes the height. I don't need this because The `RecyclerView` is scrollable. When I add new item, the height doesn't change. which is not I wanted.